# THREEJS: Converting fonts from otf and ttf to json

Tags: fonts, three.js

I have 2 different fonts, one with otf extension and the other is with ttf. I want to use it with THREE js, so I converted both to json extension so I can use it with THREE js.
I converted it using [Facetype.js](https://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/).

When I used the converted files in THREE js, "O" and "D" and other characters with holes didn't render correctly. [Image 1](https://ibb.co/cE3zTz)

I converted fonts again by checking "Reverse font direction" option which solved the problem but made another problem: all round characters (U, O, D, G, ...) are not softly rendered. [Image 2](https://ibb.co/cm3uve)

Comment: One of the parameters you pass to the constructor of `THREE.TextGeometry()` is `curveSegments` (default value is 12). Try to play with its value, increasing it.

Comment: Can you please add this as an answer to mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option.

When you create `THREE.TextGeometry()`/`THREE.TextBufferGeometry()`, you pass string of text and an object of [parameters](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/TextGeometry.parameters). One of those parameters is `curveSegments`(default value is 12). You can increase its value to get better shapes of letters.

And keep in mind, that the higher value you use, the more vertices you'll get in the geometry.

r95